# Rails CanCan - wrong number of arguments (0 for 2+)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancan, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I've got this code:

```
  def edit
    @ship = Ship.find(params[:id])
    authorize! if can? :create, @ship
    #authorize! if can? :update, @ship
    #unauthorized! if cannot? :update, @ship
  end
```

And I am getting this error:

```
ArgumentError at /ships/4/edit
wrong number of arguments (0 for 2+)
```

Which is highlighting this line:

```
authorize! if can? :create, @ship
```

I've tried quite a few things, but also what we had before, which was just:

```
authorize! @ship
```

And short of re-writing the user system with roles I'm not sure how to solve this.

This is my ability class:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    #if !user
    if user.try(:admin?)
      can :manage, :all
      return
    elsif !user
      can :read, Ship
      can :read, Planet
      return
    else
      can :read, :all
      #can :manage, Ship, :user_id => user.id
      can :manage, Ship do |ship|
        ship.try(:user) == user
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: There is a new gem CanCanCan to replace CanCan - as CanCan is no longer maintained. Switching over is so easy even I was able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`authorize!`](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/440bd887008820efbee8b954790f79b48d8264a6/lib/cancan/ability.rb#L201) method requires two parameters at least - `action` and `subject`, so your code should probably look like:

```
authorize! :create, @ship if can? :create, @ship
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to fix it by doing: 
    authorize! :update, @ship